# ¿Esta función me hace perder los datos obtenidos?

Tags: c

Si utilizo `clrscr();` en un codigo en C para limpiar pantalla, ¿pierdo los datos que obtuve antes de realizar el clrscr()?

Comment: no queda clara tu publicación, preguntas o afirmas?

Comment: El uso de los signos de interrogación indica que es una pregunta colega.

Comment: Hola Carolina, trata de realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] para que sean de utilidad no solo a tí si no a toda la comunidad, puedes realizar también este tipo de preguntas en [chat], saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu duda:

La función no borra los datos que almacenaste en variables, ya que estos en sí, están en la memoria que el programa utiliza para ejecutarse. Lo que hace la función es simplemente limpiar la pantalla donde muestras tu programa y posicionar el cursor en la posición (1,1), sería como pasar a la siguiente hoja en blanco en un cuaderno, los datos que antes escribiste en el, no estarán borrados y, por así decirlo, empezarás a escribir en esa nueva hoja en el principio del primer renglón.